# What is the purpose of the $addControl method in AngularJS FormController?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was browsing the Angular docs and I came across the [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) class. I see that there are a couple of methods for adding controls and removing them, namely `$addControl()` and `$removeControl()`. I assume these will be used for dynamically adding and removing form controls, but how exactly do I go about using them?

Comment: yup it can be used to dynamically add controls on the fly. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/291d7c467fba51a9cb89cbeee62202d51fe64b09/src/ng/directive/form.js#L125 and when you have input with ng-model this is done automatically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formController` tracks a set of child input controls in it for the purposes of setting the controllers of these child input controls on the scope, and of tracking the `$dirty`/`$pristine`, `$valid`/`$invalid`, etc... status of the form based its child controls.

This API is called by `ngModelController` - which is how Angular implements its built-in (and provides hooks for custom) input controls and by `formController` - of sub-forms to register themselves with their parent `formController`.

If you implement custom input controllers that `require: "ngModel"` (i.e. custom input controls that support the `ngModel` abstraction layer), then this is done for you.

And for the vast majority of cases, this is sufficient. But, presumably, one could implement their own `ngModel`-like directive, then this API could be used to register the non-`ngModel` control with a `formController`.

Comment: So basically as long as there is an input element that has an `ng-model` property or a directive that requires ngModel or has `ng-model` as part lf its template, then I don't explicitly have to call the `$addControl()` method? If that's the case, then is code like this considered correct: http://jsfiddle.net/kshep92/mtzuaygp/5/

Comment: @kshep92, `ngModel` is what does `$addControl`. Vast majority of directives that implement input controls (e.g. `input`, `select`, [any custom control](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example), etc...) use the `ngModel` approach, and for those, there is no need to worry about `$addControl`

Comment: I'm using `ngModel` on a custom control, but it's parent form has no entry for it. :(

Comment: I would add that having two inputs with the same ngModel will result in the ngModel not being added